# Generating a custom Sitecore log on a button click

Tags: sitecore, log4net, sitecore8, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Can we generate a custom log file in Sitecore on a button `click()` event? I know the concept of creating Sitecore custom log files on per day to day basis, but I am not able to generate the log file every time while clicking on a button.

Comment: Mite be better to ask on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the use case? If you need to filter out smth, write a wrapper to append trailing marker in front, like Log.Info($"[Ritu]: {message}, this)